# Is it possible to import button location of a form from SQL/MySQL database in ASP.net?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, sql-server

I have 2 questions which I am unable to find a solution for days in row, and was really hopping any one of you here could help me.

**1**. I'm trying to create a website/app which will allow the user design a software they like and after they click finish, the location of those buttons to be saved on a DB, SQL Server or MySQL (sql favorites).

The users will have just to Drag-and-Drop buttons, textboxes and comboboxes into a empty panel.

With basics I can understand something like

```
    Button1 btn1 = new Button1();
```

in C# this is how I used to create buttons, but not sure how to do something like this in asp.net + css.

And after the user has finished, when he clicks 'Save Button' those details will enter in a database.

Connecting to SQL Server is easy for me, but I am not able to understand the function, the code how to set the location or those buttons, when the page loads, those to go in the location they are listed in the SQL DataBase. Can it be done only by editing the location in asp.net, or even in stylesheet.css (It would be good if there is any solution in to do this by editing the location in CSS)

**2**. How can you declare a single color and then add it to all the textboxes, buttons etc in CSS.

Example code in C#

```
var MainColor = Color.Red;

Textbox1.BackgroundColor = MainColor;
```

is it even possible?

Thank you very much for considering this, and for any suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You could design your database tables to emulate the C# properties of the items you want to offer. Then you build your UI at runtime using the properties of the buttons or textboxes the user chose at design time. If you build in a primary key that identifies the user and which UI they want to use (maybe offered as a dropdown if there are more than one possibility), then you can get the rows of data necessary to build the UI on the fly.

**Edit:**
Take for example a simple button in an ASP.NET application.  It will have numerous properties associated with it, but I'm only going to show a few:

- DataType
- ID
- CssClass
- Height
- Text
- Width

In your application, you'd allow the user to drag a button onto the page, and modify it as they see fit.  Once they have it how they like, you provide some method of saving that button's properties to your database for recall when they start the new page again.

There are a couple of different ways to store the data, but where I work, we've largely settled onto a set of key-value pairs so that you can simply name the thing you're interested in (the key), and then store the value associated with that key, they'd just be varchar datatypes, and if you need to store something else, you use some method to parse the string or object.  So your tables might look something like this:

| ID | OwnerID | PageID | Key | Value |

So, to store your button's properties, you'd make an AJAX call to a web method to process the string (if you haven't read the excellent articles by [**Dave Ward**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31346131/jquery-ajax-post-object-to-asp-net-webmethod-having-dynamic-datattypes) on how to do this, I highly recommend them).

For user 1 using her first page, and ignoring the ID (as it should be an autoincrementing value), your SQL statement might look something like this (MySQL syntax example):

```
INSERT INTO MyTableName (OwnerID, PageID, Key, Value)
VALUES 
(1, 1, "DataType", "Button"),
(1, 1, "ID", "btnSubmit"),
(1, 1, "CssClass", "Buttons"),
(1, 1, "Height", "10"),
(1, 1, "Text", "Submit"),
(1, 1, "Width", "40");
```

To build the page at runtime, query the database for the items associated with her page, something like:

```
DataTable dt = SELECT * FROM MyTableName WHERE OwnerID = 1 and PageID = 1;
```

Then use the returned datatable's data to build the page dynamically.

```
string btnName = new Button();
btnName.ID = dt["ID"].value;
btnName.CssClass = dt["CssClass"].value;
//etc.
```

This is a completely untested and uncompiled example quickly created to give you an idea of how to move forward.  Hopefully it's helpful.

**2nd Edit:**  In order to get the position of the button (or other elements), you're going to have to use JavaScript to get them, and send those to your backend via a Data Transfer Object (see reference to Dave Ward's methods for doing exactly this above).  [**This SO question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829252/how-to-find-coordinates-of-an-html-button-or-image-cross-browser) should get you pointed in the right direction for getting the coordinates for the element.

Comment: I'm not really sure if I understood what you meant sir, but thank you, I will search for that in google.

Comment: I've added more detail that'll hopefully give you a path ahead.

Comment: thanks delliottg. It gave me the idea of how to put those into the database. but it left me with few questions. 1. since I am using the design of the buttons in a stylesheet in css format. the code you wrote for the returned data. should be on page load in page.aspx.cs? 2. when inserting the data. since I wont be able to write those manually in (1, 1, "DataType", "Button") but the software will detect them,  how will it understand which is the name of the button? or the height or where is it located?
.
yet. thanks for the post. it was really helpful

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to answer to the second question, because a did not really understand the first one. You should define a CSS Class and it to all the controller you wish using the property CssClass in the ASPNET control.

Comment: at the first one, I am trying to make a simple platform. Where the user can drag and drop buttons in the platform, after he is finished with the editing the form, and pressing Save. The location of those buttons, colors and everything else he added to be saved in a table in database. And when the user Logins next time, the form will show as he edited. On PageLoad, should be a code to add those buttons in the same form those was saved before from the user.

Also, thanks for editing my post, looks like I made few mistakes from rushing